# Tkinter process not shown during run

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I am running a creature simulator in python 2.7 using tkinter as my visualizer. The map is made up of squares, where colors represent land types, and a red square represents the creature. I use canvas.move, to move that red square around the board. It has to move quite a lot. But I know exactly where it should start and where it should end. I have run the simulation, bit by bit, and when it is regulated to maybe two moves ie. the sim isn't really running I'm just testing it. I can see the movements. But when I really run the sim, everything buzzes by and all I can see of the canvas is the map, but no creature and certainly no creature movement. So my question is this. Firstly, how can I possibly slow down the process so that I can see the movements? Or why would the simulation run and now show any of the tkinter?

The simulation is quite large and it would be hard to pick out just the important bits, so the code below is more of a simplification. But it matches how I did the tkinter stuff. My sim just added more calculations and loops. It's worth noting that this example works perfectly.

Driver.py:

```
from Tkinter import *
import animation


class Alien(object):
    def __init__(self):
        #Set up canvas
        self.root = Tk()
        self.canvas = Canvas(self.root, width=400, height=400)
        self.canvas.pack()
        #Vars
        self.map = [[1, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 1, 0]]
        self.x = 0
        self.y = 0
        r = 50
        self.land = {}
        #Draw Init
        for i, row in enumerate(self.map):
            for j, cell in enumerate(row):
                color = "black" if cell else "green"
                self.canvas.create_rectangle(r * i, r * j, r * (i + 1), r * (j + 1),
                                             outline=color, fill=color)
                self.land[(i, j)] = self.canvas.create_text(r * i, r * j, anchor=NE, fill="white", text="1", tag=str((i, j)))
        self.creature = self.canvas.create_rectangle(r * self.x, r * self.y, r * (self.x + 1), r * (self.y + 1),
                                                     outline="red", fill="red")
        self.canvas.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
        #Action
        movement = animation.Animation(self.root, self.canvas, self.creature, self.land)
        self.root.after(0, movement.animate)
        #Clost TK
        self.root.mainloop()
a = Alien()
```

animation.py:

```
from random import randrange
import sys


class Animation():
    def __init__(self, root, canvas, creature, land):
        self.x = self.y = 0
        self.ctr = 10
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.creature = creature
        self.root = root
        self.land = land
        #self.root.after(250, self.animate)
        self.canvas.move(self.creature, 2 * 50, 2 * 50)

    def animate(self):
        self.ctr -= 1
        if self.ctr > 0:
            for i in range(2):
                i = randrange(1, 5)
                if i == 1:
                    self.y = -1
                elif i == 2:
                    self.y = 1
                elif i == 3:
                    self.x = -1
                elif i == 4:
                    self.x = 1
                #root.after(250, self.animate(canvas, creature))
                """Moves creature around canvas"""
                self.movement()
            self.root.after(250, self.animate)

    def movement(self):
        self.canvas.move(self.creature, self.x * 50, self.y * 50)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can slow down the process using tkinters `after` method which can be used by any difrent widget.

```
canvas.after(time, dosomething) #the first parameter is how many milliseconds it will wait before it will call the second parameter.
```

where your dosomething function should be your way of updating the your cnavas.

http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/universal.html